# Converting a for loop to lambda

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

My traditional for loop way is

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
{
    if ((i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0))
    {
        result += i;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

How can I do this using a lambda instead?

Comment: (i => i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)?

Comment: Here goes another speed typing contest :)

Comment: Sounds like another homework assignment to me..LOL

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Where(i => i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0).Sum()
```

Or

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Sum(i => i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 ? i : 0)
```

Comment: This is only incidentally correct, since you should be using `.Range(0, 1000)`.  The parameters correspond to `start` and `count` not `start` and `end`.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = Enumerable
            .Range(0, 1000)
            .Sum(i => (i % 3 == 0) || (i % 5 == 0) ? i : 0);
```

This should do it.